# How to get 'Char' values from Postgres with Anorm

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework-2.0, anorm

I have a postgres table -

```
CREATE TABLE "Contest"
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  type char(1) NOT NULL,
  status char(1) NOT NULL,
  ...
)
```

I'm trying to get field values `type` and `status` back to my Play 2.x (Anorm) application:

```
 val parseContest = {
  get[Pk[Int]]("id") ~
  get[String]("name") ~
  get[Char]("type") ~
  get[Char]("status") map {
  case id~name~c_type~status =>
    Contest(id, name, c_type, status)
  }
}
```

and get error:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter extractor: anorm.Column[Char]
```

Looks like 'Char' is not supported by anorm. 
What should I change in my code? Is it good practice to use `get[String]("status")` and then `status.head` as workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could write an implicit converter for your `char` columns. That would look like this:

```
implicit def columnToChar: Column[Char] = {
    Column[Char](transformer = {
      (value, meta) =>
        val MetaDataItem(qualified, nullable, clazz) = meta
        value match {
          case ch: String => Right(ch.head)
          case _ => Left(TypeDoesNotMatch("Cannot convert " + value + " to Char for column " + qualified))
        }
    })
  }
```

Then be sure this converter is in scope.

I'm not sure the value would be a String but you can check it and make the corresponding corrections.

Answer (score 1):

There is recently merged PR on Anorm about that: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/2189